# Anytime I add a ViewController or NavigationController to my project Xcode , the auto generated code is in Objective-C and not in SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode

The project template set as  "code -> swift", " devices-> Universal". 
Initially generated code is all in SWIFT and works fine. The Obj-C is generated when i add another controller, segway.

I uninstalled 6.3.x and installed 6.4 BETA to see if that fixes the issue. 
I am at a loss. Thanks for help.

The generated code for View Controller is as follows:

```
/*
UIViewController is a generic controller base class that manages a view. It has methods that are called
when a view appears or disappears.

Subclasses can override -loadView to create their custom view hierarchy, or specify a nib name to be loaded
automatically. This class is also a good place for delegate & datasource methods, and other controller
stuff.
*/

@class UIView;
@class UINavigationItem, UIBarButtonItem, UITabBarItem;
@class UISearchDisplayController;
@class UIPopoverController;
@class UIStoryboard, UIStoryboardSegue;
@class UIScrollView;
@protocol UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator;

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIModalTransitionStyle) {
UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical = 0,
UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal,
UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve,
UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_2),
};

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIModalPresentationStyle) {
UIModalPresentationFullScreen = 0,
```

..... more Obj-c code

Comment: when you add file, have you checked if the Language is swift?

Comment: When I add a file it works fine ( as long as I choose SWIFT) .. but when I pull a component from Library ( Right bottom corner panel ) it automatically generates in Obj-C  ( not in expected Swift!) .  Thanks for the question .